# Can Anadi walk on walls?

Tags: pathfinder-2e, races

After a discussion with a player of mine about [Anadi](https://2e.aonprd.com/Ancestries.aspx?ID=42) I noticed, that contrary to what my instincts said (because they are spiders) I saw nothing about them able to crawl up walls in any other way than humans do.

Do I overlook here something or do they really have no ability to crawl walls or hang from ceilings at all?

Answer (score 8):

## Not Until Level 9*

Per RAW, Anadi PCs don't have the ability to climb walls in [Spider Form](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=730) until level 9, when they can get [Strand Strider](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=2772) as an ancestry feat. However, before then, you aren't flat-footed while climbing in Spider Form, so there is some minor benefit.

*Well, they can't get a climb speed from their ancestry until level 9; it's possible to get it earlier, such as through spells or items.

### Should a GM just give climb speed?

The [advice on flying PCs from the Ancestry Guide](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=1458) applies well here:

> Certain ancestries, such as strix or sprites, have wings. The presented ancestry rules intend to provide a good combination of story and game balance for most groups. However, some players might have character concepts that don't fit this assumption and might wish to fly from initial character creation. At the GM's discretion, the GM can grant these PCs a 15-foot fly Speed, replacing any other abilities that involve flying, such as the strix's Wings ancestral trait. In this case, any feat that upgrades the PC's flying capabilities, such as the strix's Fledgling Flight and Juvenile Flight feats, might instead upgrade this Speed by an additional 5 feet. However, GMs who allow this option should be aware that a PC who can constantly fly can trivialize many low- and mid-level challenges, consistently outshining or leaving other characters behind; the GM should consider this option very carefully before allowing it and adjust the game accordingly.

A climbing speed is less potentially problematic than a flying speed, and given it's restrictions to spider form, I'd be fairly comfortable giving out a 15 foot climb speed at level one, maybe in exchange for a heritage or 1st level ancestry feat if I was really worried about it. It's about as powerful as a permanent level 2 spell ([Spider Climb](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=299), appropriately), but in my experience (and depending on your campaign) climbing has rarely been helpful. The few times it has, [Assurance (Athletics)](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=756) has made it a non-issue for our Rogue. So limiting it to Spider Form should make it pretty safe for the first few levels; I might also limit the benefit from applying in [Hybrid Shape](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=2770) until they take the level 9 feat Strand Strider. If there's an abuse case, it'd be through Hybrid Form (which makes things like spellcasting a lot easier).

Comment: I might add a middle ground option; there is narrative potential to reduce Climb DC's and allow them to Climb normally impassable surfaces (sheer cliffs and ceilings) with an appropriate Athletics check until level 9.